# Turn on Console Logging Based On ASP.NET 5 Server Type

Tags: asp.net, logging, console, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to add console logging if the application is started using the console. More information in the official documentation on [Logging in ASP.NET 5](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/logging.html). How can I tell if the application is running under the console?

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    if (We are running under the console)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole();
    }

    app.Run(async (context) =>
    {
        var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("LoggingSample.Startup");
        logger.LogInformation("Writing output.");
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
    });
}
```

Comment: Did you try with: await context.Response.WriteAsync(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COMPUTERNAME")); ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to exclude logging when running Kestrel behind IIS/IIS Express, one option is to use the `HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT` environment variable added by the HttpPlatformHandler native module:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT"))) {
    // Only enable logging when running Kestrel or WebListener
    // without IIS acting as a reverse-proxy.
}
```

---

Determining whether your app is hosted by WebListener can be done using the `ServerFeatures` property of the application builder:

```
if (app.ServerFeatures.Any(feature => feature.Key == typeof(WebListener))) {
    // Add server-specific features here.
}
```

Comment: I don't this this is still applicable in Beta 8 since we are using the Kestrel server. Is there a way to specifically test for running in the console?

Comment: Then, it's a different question. You should remove the `WebListener Server` mention in your original post.

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: Answer updated. That said, you should strongly consider using environment names (see `IHostingEnvironment` and `IsDevelopment()/IsProduction()`) instead of trying to tag the server used to host your app.